# how to consolidate data from 2 sources in R based on rules

Tags: r

I have a dataset containing daily dosing records from 2 sources. Source 1 has the start and end days of dosing, but no clock time. Source 2 has the start and end days (the end day is the same as the start day) and clock time. Note that Source 1 start and end days can overlap with the dosing records from Source 2. For example,

| ID | AMOUNT | day.start | day.end | DOSE.TIME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 0 | 0 | 9:48 |
| 1 | 10 | 0 | 6 | . |
| 1 | 0 | 7 | 7 | . |
| 1 | 10 | 8.13 | 8.13 | 12:58 |
| 1 | 10 | 8 | 13 | . |
| 1 | 10 | 13.99 | 13.99 | 9:45 |
| 1 | 10 | 14 | 20 | . |
| 1 | 10 | 21 | 28 | . |
| 1 | 10 | 22.05 | 22.05 | 11:00 |
| 2 | 10 | 0 | 0 | 9:50 |
| 2 | 10 | 0 | 22 | . |
| 2 | 10 | 7.01 | 7.01 | 10:04 |
| 2 | 10 | 13.01 | 13.01 | 10:00 |

Here is the R code to produce this original dataset:

```
data=data.frame(ID=c(rep(1,9),rep(2,4)),
            AMOUNT=c(rep(10,2),0,rep(10,10)),
            day.start=c(0,0,7,8.13,8,13.99,14,21,22.05,0,0,7.01,13.01),
            day.end=c(0,6,7,8.13,13,13.99,20,28,22.05,0,22,7.01,13.01),
            DOSE.TIME=c('9:48',NA,NA,'12:58',NA,'9:45',NA,NA,'11:00','9:50',NA,'10:04','10:00'))
```

I want to consolidate the dosing records from both sources together without overlapping day.start and day.end, and Source 2 (containing the clock time) is more important than Source 1. Also note that the column AMOUNT can change values from row to row, so only the records with the same AMOUNT and on consecutive days can be combined. So the consolidated dosing records should look like this:

| ID | AMOUNT | day.start | day.end | DOSE.TIME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 0 | 0 | 9:48 |
| 1 | 10 | 1 | 6 | . |
| 1 | 0 | 7 | 7 | . |
| 1 | 10 | 8.13 | 8.13 | 12:58 |
| 1 | 10 | 9 | 13 | . |
| 1 | 10 | 13.99 | 13.99 | 9:45 |
| 1 | 10 | 15 | 20 | . |
| 1 | 10 | 21 | 21 | . |
| 1 | 10 | 22.05 | 22.05 | 11:00 |
| 1 | 10 | 23 | 28 | . |
| 2 | 10 | 0 | 0 | 9:50 |
| 2 | 10 | 1 | 6 | . |
| 2 | 10 | 7.01 | 7.01 | 10:04 |
| 2 | 10 | 8 | 12 | . |
| 2 | 10 | 13.01 | 13.01 | 10:00 |
| 2 | 10 | 14 | 22 | . |

Is there an easy way to code this?

Comment: Could you please share the corresponding sample input from Source 1? And while the HTML tables are pretty, they are somewhat difficult to import into R - if you wouldn't mind sharing the sample data with `dput()` that would be nicely copy/pasteable while including all structure and class information. For example, `dput(source1[1:10, ])` for the first 10 rows.

Comment: @Gregor Thomas, I've updated the post to include the R code to produce the original dataset. Thank you very much for your help and input!

Comment: @Ronak Shah, I've updated the post to include the R code to produce the original dataset. Thank you very much for your help and input! (It only allows me to notify one user at a time, so I have to repeat my comment)

Comment: Okay, I thought there were 2 data sets, but maybe there is just one? When you say "Source 1" and "Source 2", do you mean the values in the `ID` column? Or, maybe whenever there is a `Dose.Time` value. Examining the input and output I'm beginning to get an idea of what you want. Can you explain row 7 to me? Why does the 14 change to 15? In the output, where does row 8 come from? It doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @GregorThomas, 2 sources based on whether there is a DOSE.TIME value. Regarding row 7 (day.start=13.99), basically after rounding, it is 14. Because these are dosing records, and each day the subjects (ID=1, 2) get one dose. So the next row should have day.start=15, not 14 anymore. In the output, row 8 (day.start=21) is a new row, because in the original dataset, ID=1 gets daily doses from day 21 through day 28. Because there is a row (day.start=22.05) with clock time (DOSE.TIME), that row has precedence. So the row with day.start=21 & day.end=28 get broken into 2 lines in the new dataset.